# Restrict comments wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have modified my code. Now users are able to see their comments , and administrator is able to see all users comments. But still users are not able to see the comments of admin .They only see their's..How can I achieve this..

```html
<?php

/**
 * Used as a callback by wp_list_comments() for displaying the comments.
 */
function _s_comment( $comment, $args, $depth ) 
  {
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 
    if ( 'pingback' == $comment->comment_type || 'trackback' == $comment->comment_type ) : ?>
      <li id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>" <?php comment_class(); ?>>
      <div class="comment-body">
      </div>
      <?php elseif ( $current_user_id == $comment->user_id || ($current_user->roles[0] == 'administrator' ) : ?> 

       <li id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay i have find out the solution here it is

if( $current_user_id == $comment->user_id || $post->post_author == $comment->user_id )